IIS created website not running locally, But runs when is created under "Default Web Site"
Under IIS, I have created a website and published a blazor server app under it with <base href="/" /> set before publish.
While I successfully published my blazor servers tens of times under "Default Web Site", when I create a separate site it dosn't work:
Application Pool: BlazorApp8_2 "No Managed Code" "Integrated", has access to my database as db_owner, Login: IIS APPPOOL\BlazorApp8_2
Site Settings: 
Pool: BlazorApp8_2
Bindings: https:*:443:apps,http:*:80:apps
ID: 2
Name: BlazorApp8
Physical Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\BlazorApp8_2
.. Credentials: ClearText
Preload Enabled: true
Enabled Protocols: https

I type: http://apps or https://apps in the browser. which fails, The only warning I get is:

There was an error during processing of the managed application
service auto-start for  application pool: 'BlazorApp8_2'.  Some
application services may not have been processed  correctly.  Please
check the configuration for application service auto-start for the
application(s) assigned to this application pool.  The data field
contains the error code.

How to run this?

could you try removing the  from the file. try to set iis app pool permission o the site root folder. set iis site to Preload Enabled=true.i notice you have set apps as your site bindings , make sure you have set the  custom host in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file.
